# symmetric difference of temperate zone and inscribed disk

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics, tiling

For random domino tilings of the Aztec diamond of order $n$ or random lozenge tilings of the regular hexagon of order $n$, what's the typical order of magnitude of the area of the symmetric difference between the temperate zone of the tiling and the inscribed disk?

Also, what is the typical size of the maximal inward and outward radial fluctuations?  That is, let $R^+$ be the radius of the smallest centered disk that contains the temperate zone, and let $R^-$ be the radius of the largest centered disk that is contained in the temperate zone; what is the typical magnitude of $R^+-R$ and $R-R^-$, where $R$ is the radius of the inscribed disk?